# Kickstart script seems to be skipping over %post

Tags: fedora, kickstart

I have set up a Kickstart script for Fedora 25 Server, and part of that includes some things in the `%post` section, including generating a root password and calling a Slack webhook to notify me with an encrypted message. When I run the script, I see no errors, but I do not get the message from the server with the GPG-encrypted password. The script is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/HV96vxji (Do note that I have redacted some information for security)

Comment: Perhaps the curl command failed; can you redirect the output and return code to a file on the server?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I manually tested the scenario on my local system, recreating the exact steps I put in the script, and it goes fine

Comment: Log the section to a file using `%post --log=/mylog ...`

Comment: I figured out the webhook error, but now GPG is outputting a null string on the decryption end.

Comment: You should remove the ` -X POST` as curl will produce the correct header due to the `--data-urlencode` option.